# Как дать полный доступ к записи в реестре для всех пользователей в домене?

Tags: c#, реестр

Пытаюсь настроить права для всех пользователей в доменной группе на локальной машине. Делаю вроде всё правильно делаю:

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(@"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AxControls.PMFActiveX");
                            RegistrySecurity rs = new RegistrySecurity();
                            WindowsIdentity id = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
                            rs.AddAccessRule(new RegistryAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.AccountDomainUsersSid, id.User.AccountDomainSid), RegistryRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
                            key.SetAccessControl(rs);
```

ошибок в коде нет, но всё равно не работает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так?(

Comment: От имени Администратора софт запускаете? Рязрядность ОС и софта?

Comment: Так же Registry.ClassesRoot уже открывает эту ветку. Т.е. повторно писать HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT не нужно.

Comment: у меня ОС Win8 x64, приложение которое пишу направлено на x86 архитектуру. запускаю от имени администратора (без него вылетает ошибка)

Comment: @Alexis, большое спасибо! я и правда ошибся продублировав ветвь два раза:(

Comment: Проблема решена?

Comment: да, теперь всё работает, ещё раз спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Registry.ClassesRoot` уже открывает ветку `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`. Т.е. повторно писать `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` не нужно.